# C++ function to tell whether a given function is injective

Tags: c++

This might seem like a weird question, but how would I create a C++ function that tells whether a given C++ function that takes as a parameter a variable of type X and returns a variable of type X, is injective in the space of machine representation of those variables, i.e. never returns the same variable for two different variables passed to it?

(For those of you who weren't Math majors, maybe check out this page if you're still confused about the definition of injective: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function)

For instance, the function

```
double square(double x) { return x*x};
```

is not injective since `square(2.0)` = `square(-2.0)`,

but the function

```
double cube(double x) { return x*x*x};
```

is, obviously.

The goal is to create a function

```
 template <typename T>
 bool is_injective(T(*foo)(T))
 {
    /* Create a set std::set<T> retVals;
       For each element x of type T: 
       if x is in retVals, return false;
       if x is not in retVals, add it to retVals;
       Return true if we made it through the above loop.
    */
 }
```

I think I can implement that procedure except that I'm not sure how to iterate through every element of type T. How do I accomplish that?

Also, what problems might arise in trying to create such a function?

Comment: That smells intractable...

Comment: Isn't that similar to the Halting problem? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem -- i.e 'you cannot!'

Comment: I bet `cube` is not injective.  `double` is a very different thing from "real number".

Answer (score 2):

You need to test every possible bit pattern of length `sizeof(T)`.

There was a widely circulated blog post about this topic recently: [There are Only Four Billion Floats - So Test Them All!](http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/theres-only-four-billion-floatsso-test-them-all/)

In that post, the author was able to test all 32-bit floats in 90 seconds.  Turns out that would take a few centuries for 64-bit values.

So this is only possible with small input types.

Multiple inputs, structs, or anything with pointers are going to get impossible fast.

BTW, even with 32-bit values you will probably exhaust system memory trying to store all the output values in a `std::set`, because `std::set` uses a lot of extra memory for pointers.  Instead, you should use a bitmap that's big enough to hold all `2^sizeof(T)` output values.  The specialized `std::vector<bool>` should work.  That will take `2^sizeof(T) / 8` bytes of memory.

Comment: I could add: if (sizeof(T) > 4) throw("We don't have a few centuries to run this function, bro.");

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you need is [`std::numeric_limits`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/limits/numeric_limits/). To store the results, you may use an [`unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) (from `std` if you're using C++11, or from `boost` if you're not).

You can check the limits of the data types, maybe something like this *might* work (it's a dumb solution, but it may get you started):

```
template <typename T>
bool is_injective(T(*foo)(T))
{
    std::unordered_map<T, T> hash_table;

    T min = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    T max = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();

    for(T it = min; i < max; ++i)
    {
        auto result = hash_table.emplace(it, foo(it));
        if(result.second == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Of course, you may want to restrict a few of the possible data types. Otherwise, if you check for floats, doubles or long integers, it'll get very intensive.

Answer (score 1):

> but the function
>
> ```
>    double cube(double x) { return x*x*x};
> ```
>
> is, obviously.

It is obviously *not*.  There are 2^53 more `double` values representable in [0..0.5) than in [0..0.125).

Comment: If a function takes one input parameter and returns the same type then the odds of it being injective are infinitesimal, purely because of the problem of mapping n-inputs to n-outputs without generating the same output twice. It's the birthday paradox on steroids.

If you ignore some outputs (say, infinity) then functions such as "return 2.0 * x;" are injective - the only repeats will be the many inputs that map to infinity. Otherwise, no, never, not for interesting functions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot iterate all possible values of a type in C++.

But, even if you could, that approach would get you nowhere. If your type is a 64 bit integer, you might have to iterate through 2^64 values and keep track of the result for all of them, which is not possible.

Like other people said, there is no solution for a generic type X.

Comment: Yes, but what if your function is actually injective and you never return false? :) - It looks like I am answering to a comment that was already deleted.

Comment: Naturally, you can iterate all possible values. Just construct them as bit patterns, using char[]

Comment: In my opinion, not all bit patterns are legal. If X is something fancy (maybe with a virtual table pointer inside), you might get some interesting results.

Comment: I though we spoke about a primitive type? Only the search space size is too big.

Comment: The question does not state X is primitive. If it is, you are certainly right.

Comment: Ok, a lawyers reading shows that noone explicitly said so. My fast-reading transferred the examples to the broader question, which might not have been appropriate.